# Selecting Rows Not Equal To

Tags: r

Trying to figure out the syntax I could use to create a subset of data that does not include row numbers x:y. I'm trying to use things like `!=` but to no avail.

Comment: What does "no avail" mean exactly? Are you getting errors? Can you give some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are doing? `!=` is the not-equals comparer in R for atomic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use:

```
matrix[-(x:y),]
```

or try

```
?subset
```